# nodejs console.log doesn't print result if not in debug

Tags: node.js, fs, console.log

Not sure if it is bug or some hidden feature, but code below doesn't return anything if it is not in debugging. It supposed to return Hex buffer.

```
var fs = require("fs");
var d = fs.readFileSync("app.js");
console.log(d);
```

If I set break point on second line and debug - console.log prints buffer value.

Also all works if console.log(d.toString()).

I am developing in VSCode - may be bug with IDE?

Same code run as node app.js, outputs HEX buffer.

Any idea?

Comment: What do you use for debugging? I think that console log internally use util.inspect method. And this method can be customized. Maybe when debugging some customization is used?

Answer (score 1):

Check now, added character encoding '`utf8`'

```
var fs = require("fs");
var d = fs.readFileSync("app.js",  'utf8');
console.log(d);
```

Comment: with utf8 it works, same as .toString(). Quesiton is why vsCode doesn't show pure buffer